# What are the instrument parts, that goes under the song lyrics

Tags: composition

What do we call the instrument parts, that goes under the song lyrics?

The parts that doesn't equal to the melody of the lyrics but add lot of  fullness.

**EDIT**

Here I am talking about music parts that are normally written for violins and other strings, and some times lead guitars.

Comment: probably you mean right hand of the piano accompaniment. I would call it harmonisation, arpeggios or even counterpoint.

Comment: @AlbrechtHügli I edited the question

Comment: "...normally written for violins and other strings..."  you need to get out more :-) . A jazz singer has an entire swing band behind them, for example.  In any case,  the three terms in @AlbrechtHügli 's comment are correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The *accompaniment* and the *bass line* are the usuals. Accompaniment as it accompanies the melody, the bass line as it's played by the bass, or the left hand on piano. Sometimes all that is called the *chords* which would be played on guitar or piano - the main two instruments that play multiple notes. Occasionally there is a *drum pattern*.

EDIT: now a different question, partially. The guitar part could be the *riff*, and strings/horns be the accompaniment again.